# Can someone explain whats incide function "web3.eth.getBlock("latest")"

Tags: web3js

I want to understand how the web3.js library works.

Could you please explain what happens "under the carpet" of the function

```
web3.eth.getBlock("latest")
```

Yes exactly the **last** block.

If you look in the ethereum specs, you can see that each block contains extra data. Which has a `Parent hash`, hence we can conclude that going down the blocks is pretty easy.

But I still do not understand how the library finds the `last block` (at low level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize your web3 object, you pass it a RPC URL that is an URL pointing to a node which is synchronized to the blockchain, this is this node that will return the last block it know.